# Как менять страницы загружаемого контента при прокрутке swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, pagination

У меня есть TableViewController и там отображаются новости. Мне надо каждый когда прокрутка дойдет до конца загружать новости из API с pagination.

Сперва я загружаю `https://****.**/api/posts` что равняет странице 1.

Потом мне надо загрузить страницу 2 так:
`https://****.**/api/posts?page=2`

Как каждый раз менять цифру страницы?

```
let downloader = Downloader()
var page = 2

override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let url = "https://****.**/api/posts?page=\(page))"

    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y > self.lastOffsetY) {
        downloader.getLastestNews(url)
    }
}

override func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    lastOffsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как делаю я, во первых запрос на сервер включает в себя post или get запрос с параметром page и соотвественно в зависимости от page возвращает данные к примеру page = 1 возвращает 20, затем page = 2 возвращает от 20 до 40 и тд. У меня есть метод который делает запрос на сервер и парсит данные

`startDownload(page: Bool, isNew: False)`

у тебя он может быть другой.

у UITableViewDataSource есть метод

`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

там я и обрабатываю количество ячеек, а затем загрузку:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == self.goodsItems.count - 2 && !self.flagOfEmptyMas && !self.flagForDownloadingMas {
        startDownload(page: true, isNew: false)
    }
}
```

если текущая ячейка = (количеству элементов массива - 2 т.е 18) то подгружай данные, уже с page2 и тд.

советую еще поставить крутилку внизу таблицы

```
self.myTableView.tableFooterView = self.spinner
```

Удачи.

Comment: Нет, вопрос был в том как менять каждый раз страницу